# Maven: RestAssured dependencies not resolved

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, rest-assured

I"m new to Maven and try to build rest assured web service testing but the resutAssured and junit dependencies are not resolve. I have Maven 3 installed and using Intellij IDE. What wrong with it?

Below is my entire pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.peterwkc.RestAssured</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestAssured</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!--================== POM Dependencies ====================-->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error Message when hover:

Dependency 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.3' not found less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems.

Comment: You may have a typo in your xml.  You can copy the right snippet from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured  Then tell Intellij to reimport the maven projects to ensure the Maven dependencies are fetched.

Comment: In addition to the above, why aren't you using the latest version of rest-assured ? <version>3.2.0</version>

Comment: I just test with different version and see it works. I will using the latest version.

Comment: Network timeout problems. I try at Office and it works.

Comment: Problem solved.Close thread.